# seq: missing operand Try `seq --help' for more information

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
MACHINES_NUM=3
for i in $(seq $MACHINES_NUM)
do
   echo mkdir -p /something/$i
done
```

someone please help.....

Comment: did you try `seq --help`? What don't you understand about 'missing operand'? Good luck.

Comment: `seq` isn't a standard command, so it isn't *ever* guaranteed to work a specific way.

Comment: You aren't running the code you posted here.

Comment: @Gilles, are you sure? Maybe J. Random OS Vendor ships a `seq` that requires a minimum of two arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This error message suggesting the use of `--help` is obviously from GNU seq. Furthermore Jamesking has indicated that he's using Linux, which on non-embedded platforms means GNU utilities. You posit that there is a vendor that ships a utility called `seq`, which produces an error message very like the GNU version, but doesn't work in the most basic use case. I posit that the code posted here isn't the real code, and that the real code has a typo in one of the occurrences of `MACHINES_NUM`. Recommending more complex tools, instead of pointing out the real problem, is not helpful.

Comment: @Gilles, you're welcome to posit whatever you like, but since there exists no canonical specification for seq, no canonical answers may be given regarding it (without a specific implementation being part of the OP's question). That the GNU implementation is indeed _implied_ by `--help` I will grant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `seq` -- it isn't a POSIX-standardized command (or, like `bash`, a third-party tool with a single canonical implementation), so there's no guarantee that it'll work any particular way. If you have bash available, it has a C-style for syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
num_machines=3
for ((i=0; i<num_machines; i++)); do
   echo mkdir -p "/something/$i"
done
```

For POSIX sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
num_machines=3
i=; while [ $(( ( i += 1 ) <= num_machines )) -ne 0 ]; do
   echo mkdir -p "/something/$i"
done
```

---

If you want your counting to start at 1 rather than 0, these are straightforwardly modified:

```
#!/bin/bash
num_machines=3
for ((i=1; i<=num_machines; i++)); do
   echo mkdir -p "/something/$i"
done
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
num_machines=3
i=1; while [ $(( i <= num_machines )) -ne 0 ]; do
   echo mkdir -p "/something/$(( i += 1 ))"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so so much @Charles Duffy what if have to do that in reverse order like 5 4 3 2 1....

Comment: @Jamesking, then `for ((i=5; i>0; i--))` (for scripts starting with `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: @Jamesking, ...the POSIX sh equivalent (for `#!/bin/sh` scripts) being `i=5; while [ $(( ( i -= 1 ) >= 0 )) -ne 0 ]; do`.

Comment: ok thanks again for the sh script how to achieve this if it has to first check if the dir exists if it exists then it shouldn't do anything and if it doesn't then only it should create new directory. @Charles Duffy

Comment: @Jamesking, re: your suggested edit -- `mkdir -p` already does nothing if the directory already exists, so there's no need to check first.

Comment: but it is changing the time stamp of the folder that already exits

Comment: @Jamesking, on what platform? I can't reproduce that behavior on either OS X or modern Arch Linux; `mkdir -p foo.d; stat foo.d; sleep 2; mkdir -p foo.d; stat foo.d` shows the same mtime and ctime for each.

Comment: @Jamesking, ...also, that behavior doesn't make sense at an implementation level, because the underlying syscall returns with an error (`EEXIST`) when the directory already exists; `mkdir -p` just ignores that specific error status.

Comment: on what platform? platform is linux

Comment: what if it has to take the value from num_machines .the POSIX sh equivalent (for #!/bin/sh scripts) being i=5; while [ $(( ( i -= 1 ) >= 0 )) -ne 0 ]; do

Comment: @Jamesking, well, as I said, I tested on Linux, couldn't reproduce the problem, and told/showed you *exactly* how I did that test. If you *can* repro `mkdir -p` changing mtimes on a directory that already exists, by all means, ask about it as a separate question.

Comment: @Jamesking, uhh, what do you think? `i=$num_machines` rather than `i=5`. That one should be easy enough, frankly, to not need help.

Comment: yes thats easy Thanks for the help I really thank you very much for the help that you did today. @Charles Duffy

Comment: This would be a good answer if the question was “my platform doesn't have `seq`, what can I use instead?”. Since the asker does have `seq`, recommending something more complex instead of pointing out the typo is bad advice.

Comment: @Gilles, even on a platform that *does* have `seq`, no guarantees are available about its semantics or behavior. Which is my point. Suggesting use of tools with defined semantics is entirely sound advice; the added advantage of avoiding subshell and external-command-invocation overhead is gravy.